# xmlstarlet: insert svg fill attribute

Tags: svg, xpath, xml-namespaces, xmlstarlet

I'm writing a batch file using `xmlstarlet` to create coloured versions of font awesome SVG files.

Here's an example input SVG file:

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 640 512">
    <path d="PATH DATA..."/>
</svg>
```

And I want to add a `fill` attribute to the `path` element.

However, my `xmlstarlet` command is not inserting a new `fill` attribute and I just get the formatted input file as output:

```sh
xmlstarlet ed -i 'svg/path' -t 'attr' -n 'fill' -v 'purple' input_file.svg
```

Any ideas welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With xmlstarlet and use of namespace:

```
xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl \
                -N x=http://www.w3.org/2000/svg \
                --insert '//x:svg/x:path' -t attr -n "fill" -v "#ffffff" file.xml
```

Output:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 640 512">
  <path d="PATH DATA ..." fill="#ffffff"/>
</svg>
```

---

See: `xmlstarlet edit`